# Restore bower components on Visual Studio build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, bower, asp.net-core-mvc, kpm

I've just created my first ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project in VS 2015. The web application project that comes out of the box.

I figured out that bower components are stored in `wwwroot/lib` folder. I made an experiment and deleted it. After that I rebuilt the project and the bower components were **not** restored.

Calling `bower install` manually in console restored the files.

How do I make Visual Studio restore bower files automatically on build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this, though I don't really like it. I'll be happy to accept a better answer.

In project's gulpfile.js the first line is a comment"

```
/// <binding Clean='clean'/>
```

It hooks to Visual Studio `Clean` event and binds `clean` Gulp task to it.
You can hook to other events e.g. `After Build`. I bound it with a task that uses [gulp-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower) to restore the components.

gulpfile.js

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' AfterBuild='after_build'/>

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    bower = require('gulp-bower');

...

gulp.task("after_build", function() {
    return bower()
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'lib/'));
});
```

You can see the bindings in `Task Runner Explorer`:
[image]

This solution seems kind of clumsy though. I'd rather have the kpm-utility do the job.

**EDIT**

Actually there is no need for restoring the packages on build. They are restored when you open the project in VS. However I don't know what happens when you update your sources from code repository.